# Stuck making basic GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

firstly sorry I know this place isn't really somewhere to go to ask for someone to do something for you, but I'm just quite frustrated currently.

If it would be possible for someone to help me turn this:

```
grid = [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[7], [8], [9]]
```

Into something that would output:

[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]

[7] [8] [9]

Again, really sorry about asking this, but I just need all the help I can get.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask] and show us your work so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your list of lists and print each row:

```
for gridRow in grid:

    print(gridRow)
```

to get the following output

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[4], [5], [6]]
[[7], [8], [9]]
```

Additional formatting upon each iteration would be necessary to get your exact desired format:

```
for gridRow in grid:

    #map(str, gridRow) is necessary because your list contains numbers
    #if they were strings, just " ".join(gridRow) would be fine
    rowOut = " ".join(map(str, gridRow))

    print(rowOut)
```

prints exactly what you asked.

Comment: are you sure you're declaring your grid as `grid = [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[7], [8], [9]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[7], [8], [9]]

for row in grid:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using stdio you can print out the data in the format you want.

```
    import stdio

    grid = [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[7], [8], [9]]

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            stdio.write(str(grid[i][j]))
        stdio.writeln("\n")
```

[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]

[7] [8] [9]